# Find the nearest date from entered date in SQL, both ways

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem, I have a task to find a nearest date to a given date, looking both ways, older or younger. But I have no idea, I'm new to SQL, tried googling but didn't find any help.

```
create proc Task
(@Date date)
as
begin

    select top(1) p.FirstName, p.LastName, e.BirthDate, e.JobTitle  from HumanResources.Employee e
    join Person.Person p
    on p.BusinessEntityID = e.BusinessEntityID
     where e.BirthDate>@Date

end
```

I started something like this, and then lost it

Comment: Keep your top(1).  Now imagine if you sorted the data so that the most relevant result was at the top of the list?  What would you sort the data by?  Hint: Perhaps you could calculate the distance between the BirthDate and @Date as an absolute number.

Comment: (1) Sample data and desired results would really help.  (2) The code is not valid MySQL code, so the tag is confusing.

Comment: Uh, why does `Employee` have the birthday, and not `Person`?  This is a screwy data model.

Comment: Actually, why is "the job title where their birthday is closest to some arbitrary date" being used?  What are you trying to express here?

Answer (score 0):

Always remember: TOP without ORDER BY by doesn't make much sense; add an order by that is ascending (your `birthdate > @date` comparison asks for all birthdates greater than/after, so the TOP(1) ordered by birthdate ascending would be the earliest birthdate that is greater than your variable)

Then take the entire query, paste it again, put UNION ALL between them and flip your ORDER BY to be descending and your comparison to be less than, in this second query

You thus end up with a query that chooses the smallest that is greater than and the largest that is less than i.e. The nearest ones to your variable

Consider whether you should be using >= and <= if a date that is bang on meets the specification

Answer (score 0):

Use `datediff()` to get the duration between the two dates. Since you don't care whether the date is in the future or in the past, use `abs()` to get the absolute value of the duration. Then order by the absolute duration and take the top one record.

I'm not sure if you're really on MySQL or on SQL Server. The `TOP (1)` indicates SQL Server, the tag says MySQL.

Here's the MySQL version:

```
SELECT p.firstname,
       p.lastname,
       e.birthdate,
       e.jobtitle
       FROM humanresources.employee e
            INNER JOIN person.person p
                       ON p.businessentityid = e.businessentityid
       ORDER BY abs(datediff(e.birthdate, @date))
       LIMIT 1;
```

And here for SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP (1)
       p.firstname,
       p.lastname,
       e.birthdate,
       e.jobtitle
       FROM humanresources.employee e
            INNER JOIN person.person p
                       ON p.businessentityid = e.businessentityid
       ORDER BY abs(datediff(day, e.birthdate, @date));
```

May need some tweaks depending on the actual data types you're using.

---

Edit:

Addressing fifoniks's concern a version, that could perform better, if the respective indexes exist (on `humanresources.employee.birthdate` optimally once ascending and once descending).

It first gets the union of the nearest record in the the future of `@date` (including `@date`) and the analog record for the past, hopefully using indexes along the way. From these two records, the one with the lowest absolute duration to `@date` is picked. Then `person` gets joined.

```
SELECT p.firstname,
       p.lastname,
       y.bithdate,
       y.jobtitle
       FROM (SELECT TOP (1)
                    x.businessentityid,
                    x.birthdate,
                    x.jobtitle
                    FROM (SELECT TOP (1)
                                 e.businessentityid,
                                 e.birthdate,
                                 e.jobtitle
                                 FROM humanresources.employee e
                                 WHERE e.birthdate >= @date
                                 ORDER BY e.birthdate ASC
                          UNION ALL
                          SELECT TOP (1)
                                 e.businessentityid,
                                 e.birthdate,
                                 e.jobtitle
                                 FROM humanresources.employee e
                                 WHERE e.birthdate <= @date
                                 ORDER BY e.birthdate DESC) x
                    ORDER BY abs(datediff(day, x.birthdate, @date)) ASC) y
            INNER JOIN person.person p
                       ON p.businessentityid = y.businessentityid;
```

Comment: I'd never ever do this. The suggested query would calculate the function for every row in table. It cannot use indexes.

Comment: @fifonik . . . Well, we are waiting for your answer.

Comment: Two queries, one with `WHERE birthdate < @date ORDER BY birthdate DESC LIMIT 1`, another with `WHERE birthdate >= @date ORDER BY birthdate ASC LIMIT 1` then IF in the SP would be much more efficient and could use indexes.

Comment: It is better in terms of performance, however I bet the query would cause temp table generation so I'd prefer two-queries solution (I added answer). However, if one-query solution if preferable (should be in view, not in SP for example) -- it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use functions in order (as server will not be able to use indexes).
Instead, I'd go for two-queries solution.
It could be wrapped in SP something like this (MySQL version):

```
CREATE FUNCTION `Task`(
    `aDate` DATE
)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    SELECT
          `BusinessEntityID`
        , `BirthDate`
    INTO
          @id_next
        , @birthdate_next
    FROM
        `Employee`
    WHERE
        `BirthDate` >= aDdate
    ORDER BY
        `BirthDate` ASC
    LIMIT
        1
    ;

    IF @birthdate_next IS NULL THEN
        SELECT
              `BusinessEntityID`
            , `BirthDate`
        INTO
            @id_prev
          , @birthdate_prev
        FROM
            `Employee`
        WHERE
            `BirthDate` < aDate
        ORDER BY
            `BirthDate` DESC
        LIMIT
            1
        ;
    ELSE
        IF DATEDIFF(@birthdate_next, aDate) > 1 THEN
            SELECT
                  `BusinessEntityID`
                , `BirthDate`
            INTO
                @id_prev
              , @birthdate_prev
            FROM
                `Employee`
            WHERE
                    `BirthDate` < aDate
                AND `BirthDate` > DATE_SUB(aDate, INTERVAL DATEDIFF(@birthdate_next, aDate) DAY)
            ORDER BY
                `BirthDate` DESC
            LIMIT
                1
            ;
        END IF;
    END IF;

    CASE
        WHEN @id_prev IS NULL AND @id_next IS NULL THEN RETURN NULL;
        WHEN @id_prev IS NULL THEN RETURN @id_next;
        WHEN @id_next IS NULL THEN RETURN @id_prev;
        WHEN DATEDIFF(@birthdate_next, aDate) < DATEDIFF(aDate, @birthdate_prev) THEN RETURN @id_next;
        ELSE RETURN @id_prev;
    END CASE;

END
```

So in some cases only single query (the first one) would be executed.
The query will use index by BirthDate.
If the first query diff from specified date is less than 2 days, the second query will not be executed at all (it is more complicated as ordered DESC).
It is possible to further simplify the SP, however I'm keeping it "as is" so it is easier to understand.